# Helper tool for testing at different screen resolution

Tags: language-agnostic, testing, screen-resolution

I use to develop on my workstation with the screen having a resolution of 1440x900.

Often I need to switch resolution to a different one just to test if the desired results works good at these resolution (800x600, 1024x768, etc.)

I was wondering if I can instead have a tool that will automatically resize my browser window at the resolution I need to.

Does such a tool exists? how do you handle this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work for you: [Sizer](http://www.brianapps.net/sizer/)

[image]

Quote:

> Sizer is a freeware utility that
>   allows you to resize any window to an
>   exact, predefined size. This is
>   extremely useful when designing web
>   pages, as it allows you to see how the
>   page will look when viewed at a
>   smaller size. The utility is also
>   handy when compiling screen-shots for
>   documentation, using Sizer allows you
>   to easily maintain the same window
>   size across screen grabs.

And the [Screen Caliper](http://www.iconico.com/caliper/) is handy for measuring sizes of windows after-the-fact. E.g. different pop ups or forms you might need to match.

Comment: Very useful tool, I have used it off-and-on for years!

Answer (score 1):

If you want something built into your browser, here is a handy extension I've used with Chrome called [Resolution Test](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/idhfcdbheobinplaamokffboaccidbal).
Here is a similar one for Firefox called [Firesizer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5792/).

If you want to just measure things on your screen, [Measureit](http://www.kevinfreitas.net/extensions/measureit/) for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/539/) and [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/aonjhmdcgbgikgjapjckfkefpphjpgma) are really useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way, if you want to build test on your own. You can use [selenium test framework](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/) for that. With couple of code lines you can create test that will resize browser and capture screen of your site. Good thing about it if you want you can automatically test hundreds of resolution in small period of time. For example download entire screen resolution spreadsheet form google analytics and test how your site look on every resolution. After testing is complete, you only need to open folder with images and see if everything is ok.

Here is [code example](http://nikolaloncar.com/testing-web-app-or-site-automatically-on-different-screen-resolutions/).

Test can be written in **java, c#, pyton, ruby, php, perl, javascript**.